# Creating an $elemMatch mongo query using QueryDSL with spring data

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, querydsl

I want to create a query using QueryDSL to replace this:

```
@Query(value = "{mappings: {$elemMatch: {'key': ?0, 'value': {$in: ?1}}}}")
List<MyObject> findByMapping(String key, Set<String> values);
```

`MyObject` is:

```
class MyObject {
  Set<Mapping> mappings;
}
```

and `Mapping` is:

```
class Mapping {
  String key;
  String value;
}
```

I tried creating a query using `.and()` but it ends up bringing all documents that have the given key in their mappings and the values in ANY key-value pair not just those that have a matching key.

For example:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  mappings: [{
    key: 'a', value: 1
  }, {
    key: 'b', value: 3
  }, {
    key: 'a', value: 2
  }]
},
{
  _id: 2,
  mappings: [{
    key: 'a', value: 3
  }, {
    key: 'b', value: 2
  }, {
    key: 'b', value: 1
  }]
}
```

If I call `findByMapping("a", hashSet);` with `hashSet.add(1) and hashSet.add(2)` I want it to retrieve only the first document since it is the only one that has key-value pairs of `a->1` and `a->2` but it ends up retrieving both because it sees they both have mappings with the 'a' key and both have mappings with values 1 and 2.

I know I could easily replace the `Mapping` object with a simple HashMap but this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the data type of values? Is it String or Integer.. Since the document you have mentioned is having it as integer value where as while querying you are using string

Comment: let's assume it's a string just like in the pojos

Comment: I have tested the above query.. and it returns only 1 result. The query it fires is  { "mappings" : { "$elemMatch" : { "key" : "a" , "value" : { "$in" : [ "2" , "1"]}}}}

Did you tried with the proper data set? without any discrepancy.

Comment: I'll check again just to be sure

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method like this:

```java
public static <D, Q extends SimpleExpression<D>> PredicateOperation elemMatch(@NonNull ListPath<D, Q> path,
                                                                              @NonNull Q queryDocument,
                                                                              @NonNull List<Function<Q, Predicate>> predicates) {
return ExpressionUtils.predicate(
    MongodbOps.ELEM_MATCH,
    path.any(),
    ExpressionUtils.allOf(predicates
        .stream()
        .map(predicate -> predicate.apply(queryDocument)).toList())
    );
}
```

Then you can use it in the following way:

```java
personRepository.findAll(
    QPerson.person.name.eq("Luke")
            .and(elemMatch(
                QPerson.person.shippingAddresses,
                QAddress.address,
                List.of(
                    address -> address.planet.eq("Tatooine"),
                    address -> address.planet.region.eq("Outer Rim")
                )
            )));
```

Also please see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/1524